# "a streak of critical thinking" vs. "a critical thinking streak"

Tags: phrase-choice

Which one is correct?

> 1 I have a streak of critical thinking.

> 2 I have a critical thinking streak.

---

Based on the examples in the [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/streak):

> an ambitous/competitive/independent streak

> a streak of determination/independence/arrogance

I can say I should use "a streak of + noun" or "a adjective + streak"

I think critical thinking is a noun and I should use the sentence #1.

But the thing is I have checked "questioning streak" vs "streak of questioning" on [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=questioning%20streak%2Cstreak%20of%20questioning&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3) and there are only a few records of "questioning streak", but I think "questioning" is a gerund which should be used as a noun. So why do they say "questioning streak" and not "streak of questioning"?

Comment: Generally, we don't say a person has a streak of something like that. In any case, streak of questioning and questioning streak are the same thing.

Comment: @Lambie Would you please explain your sentence: "Generally, we don't say a person has a streak of something like that."? What is the problem with that? This sentence is from the Cambridge Dictionary (the link in my question) : "You need to have a competitive streak when you're working in marketing."

Comment: Yes, I would never say: I *have* a streak of critical thinking, unless it were *something like*: I have a streak of selfishness in my personality.  But this would work: She demonstrated a streak of critical thinking, which is unusual for her. To have a competitive streak as used in the dictionary sounds ok. It is saying: I have a streak of ct that is the issue.

Comment: @Lambie Do you mean we use streak for negative characteristics only? For example, when we want to refer to being a critical thinker as a one of out good characteristics we should avoid using streak, but if we want to refer to  being a critical thinker as a bad feature then we can use streak (maybe someone is an extreme critical thinker). Am I right?

Comment: That is not what I am saying. I am saying (again) we would not say: **I have a streak of critical thinking"** *unless the circumstances were unusual*. I inherited a streak of ct from my father.  A person can show or demonstrate critical thinking but not "have it" as in I have critical thinking. I am a critical **thinker**.

Comment: @Lambie I think I've got it. You mean critical thinking is an ability that we gain during our lives, it is not something that one has born with or it is not something in one's nature.

Comment: @alireza: Not really. You seem to think of "critical thinking" as a trait (in-born vs. developed over time doesn't matter here), but English speakers generally don't; it's a thing you *do*, not a thing you *have/are*. "Streak" also has two meanings, either a series of events recurring in sequence, or a component of personality (figuratively, describing personality like a painting with "paint" streaks of different traits). "Critical thinking" isn't an event or a personality trait, so neither sense of "streak" applies. For personality, we might say "a logical streak".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here you are using streak to mean "personality aspect". You certainly can use either "streak of [noun]" or "[adjective] streak" in this sense. However, which one is more common (and would sound more natural to a native speaker) will vary depending on the words in question, and may be difficult to predict. For example, "mean streak" is far more common than "streak of meanness", whereas "streak of madness" is more common than "mad streak".

The problem with looking at results for "questioning" is that this is an unusual word to use for that personality trait, especially as a noun. A native speaker might be more likely to talk about a "curious streak" or a "streak of curiosity". Both of these are far more common than the alternatives you tried. The adjective version is more common in this case, but not to an extreme degree. See [the ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=curious%20streak%2Cstreak%20of%20curiosity%2C%20questioning%20streak&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3).

I would not say either "a critical thinking streak" or "a streak of critical thinking", since this is not really part of your personality. I would be much more likely to talk about having "a talent for critical thinking" or "critical thinking ability".

Comment: hi, a "curious streak" means something different than a "streak of curiosity" which is why it has more ngrams

Answer (score 6):

The meaning of "streak" you're asking about is almost always used with an *attributive adjective*, which means *before the noun*.

When we use the structure *[ "streak of" + noun ]* it almost always has a different meaning, like "series of many unusual events in a short period of time":

> My streak of bad luck has finally come to an end.

So while "a questioning streak" usually indicates a personality trait that leads you to question things, "a streak of questioning" sounds like asking lots of questions in a short period of time, rather than a description of your personality.

Comment: I disagree about how streak is used: you often talk about "a lucky streak"; it's just that with a longer/more complex expression, it is more understandable to use "a streak of very poor decisions".

Comment: @StuartF If you read my answer carefully, I never say anything about the structure of "lucky streak". I say that (1) the meaning of "personality" only takes attributive adjectives, and (2) the structure *[ "streak of" + noun ]* only indicates a series of events, not personality. Both of these statements are true, as is my concluding paragraph.

Comment: @gotube But Longman Dictionary completely contradicts with your claim: [https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/streak]: a part of someone’s character that is different from the rest of their character:

**streak of** : 
 His serious nature was lightened by **a streak of mischief.**

Comment: And also Merriam-webster  [https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/streak] : streak of stubbornness

Comment: And also Cambridge [https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/streak]: 
a part of someone's personality: a streak of determination/independence/arrogance

Comment: @alireza Interesting! Those are reliable sources from both sides of the Atlantic, so my answer here is obviously not totally correct. But at the same time, it's gotten 5 upvotes and none down, so there's *something* to it.

Answer (score 4):

Both "questioning streak" and "streak of questioning" are probably very rare, so I suspect that that Ngram is based on only a few results and is therefore not very useful.

You can use either construction with a gerund phrase.<sup>1</sup> For example:

> The air experiences a period of rapid heating followed by a period of gradual cooling.
> The air experiences a rapid heating period followed by a gradual cooling period.

"Critical thinking" is not something that would usually happen in a "streak", so I find your original sentence to be quite unusual. If you had to write about such a streak, though, either construction would be fine.<sup>2</sup>

---

<sup>1</sup> It's probably better to consider "critical thinking" (like "questioning") a gerund phrase than a noun.

<sup>2</sup> As noted in a comment below, "critical thinking streak" is potentially ambiguous; it could mean not only a streak of critical thinking but also a critical streak of thinking.

Comment: The only issue is that a "critical thinking streak" is potentially ambiguous depending on context: it could be a critical streak of thinking (i.e. a very important streak), or a streak of critical thinking. But I agree both are grammatical.

Comment: @StuartF Thanks; I've added a note pointing out that issue.

Comment: Ngrams are not the end all and be all of the English language. Thank goodness for that. If everything had already been written, where would we be?

Comment: Would you please explain more about your sentence ""Critical thinking" is not something that would usually ...". For example, in the Cambridge dictionary I found this sentence (the link in my question) : "You need to have a competitive streak when you're working in marketing." My impression was that when "competitive" can happen in a "streak" then "critical thinking" can happen as well.

Comment: @alireza M-W defines "streak" in this sense as "[a slight admixture : TRACE](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/streak)". It is used only with certain modifiers; one can have a rebellious streak, a mean streak, a whimsical streak, etc. The gerund phrase "critical thinking" doesn't work as a modifier of "streak".

Answer (score 2):

Often seen uses of streak:
A streak of good luck
A streak of bad luck
A winning streak [cards or games or sports]
A losing streak (also cards or games or sports
A streak of losses or wins (same)

Apart the type of usage we see above, there is also:

> 2. **an element of a specified kind in someone's character**. "there's **a streak of insanity** in the family" Other meanings including the verb:
>    [Oxford Dictionary via google](https://www.google.com/search?q=define%20streak&rlz=1C1GCEU_enUS1030US1031&oq=define%20streak&aqs=chrome..69i57j0i512l9.2083j1j15&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)

- There's more than a streak of genius in his game.
- When speaking, he does display a streak of critical thinking from time to time.

Finally, a streak of critical thinking can be rendered adjectivally as a critical thinking streak. Same thing.